# Python Discord example code isn't working

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to use the example code provided on this page:
https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

I have installed all the packages but I am getting a list of errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/recBot.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run('ODEyNDg4NjcyMDEyMjcxNjg2.YDBfCg.MDhTkvacjfCSdETeGtW4weQir7U')
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/omrior/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

I am using Pycharm IDE on MacOS.
I am not sure what is the problem and would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you installed PyNaCl, libffi-dev and python3-dev ?
From their [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) page :
 `Please note that on Linux installing voice you must install the following packages via your favourite package manager (e.g. apt, dnf, etc) before running the above commands:

libffi-dev (or libffi-devel on some systems)
python-dev (e.g. python3.6-dev for Python 3.6)
`

Comment: Yes I installed PyNaCl, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for discord.py

Check the solution on the github issue: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159

Comment: It looks like this solution is made for Windows only, and I am working on MacOS.